# Flutter space icons evenly in DropDownButton uniformally and equidistant

Tags: flutter

I'm building a Flutter Web App and am hacking the appbar for my navigation. I'm creating a dropdown menu to give some more options, only I want the arrow icons to be uniform and not change the spacing. This is an example of what I want:

[image]

And this is what I have:

[image]

It's subtle but also annoying me. This is the code I have for each dropdownbutton:

```
  return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child: DropdownButton<String>(
        isExpanded: false,
        alignment: Alignment.center,

        iconSize: 15,

        value: dropdownValue,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        // elevation: 16,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          fontFamily: GoogleFonts.lora().fontFamily,
        ),

        onChanged: (String? value) {
          // This is called when the user selects an item.
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = value!;
          });
        },
```

I tried wrapping them in a sized box with equal height and width, but that also didn't work, this is the closest I've gotten them.

Comment: So you want the icon to be near the text?

Comment: basically yeah, I know it doesn't look that different but I want the Icons equally spaced from the texts